# Не удается раздавать статические файлы

Tags: rust, actix-web

Поскольку стоит задача раздавать картинки - следую следующему гайду:
https://actix.rs/docs/static-files/

Для примера создал дирректорию(`static`) в проекте и залил в нее 1 картинку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее прописываю следующий код:
(обратить внимание только на строки(их всего две) с коментариями: `// Взято из гайда`)

```
use actix_cors::Cors;
use actix_web::{http, web, get, post, App, HttpResponse, HttpServer, Result};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use actix_files::Files;  // Взято из гайда

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyObj {
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct MyParams {
    foo: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct MyResponseObj {
    name: String,
    params: MyParams,
}

#[get("/{name}")]
async fn index_get(path: web::Path<MyObj>, params: web::Query<MyParams>) -> Result<HttpResponse> {

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(MyResponseObj {
        name: path.name.to_string(),
        params: params.clone(),
    }))
}

#[post("/{name}")]
async fn index_post(path: web::Path<MyObj>, params: web::Json<MyParams>) -> Result<HttpResponse> {

    hello().await;
    println!("{:?}", params.foo);
    println!("{:?}", path.name);

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(MyResponseObj {
        name: path.name.to_string(),
        params: params.clone(),
    }))
}


#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    HttpServer::new(|| App::new()
        .wrap(
            Cors::new() // <- Construct CORS middleware builder
              .allowed_origin("http://localhost:3000")
              .allowed_methods(vec!["GET", "POST"])
              .allowed_headers(vec![http::header::AUTHORIZATION, http::header::ACCEPT])
              .allowed_header(http::header::CONTENT_TYPE)
              .max_age(3600)
              .finish())
        .service(Files::new("/static", ".")) // Взято из гайда
        .service(index_get)
        .service(index_post)

    )
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8088")?
        .run()
        .await
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Mike_Kharkov <yamaradg@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
actix-web = "3.0.1"
actix-rt = "1.1.1"
actix-cors = "0.3.0"
actix-files = "0.3.0"
postgres = "0.17.5"
serde = { version = "1.0.116", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
json = "0.12"
tokio-postgres = "0.5.5"
tokio = "0.2.22"
env_logger = "0.7.1"
```

Вопрос:
Что еще необходимо прописать(и где конкретно) что бы появилась возможность обратится к вышеуказанной картинке(допустим с локалхоста) и не получить вот такого рода ошибку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может, помог бы HTTP - код ошибки? Может, попробовать сделать get - запрос postman'ом? Как я понял, Вы факически ничего не программируете, а просто запускаете http-сервер с определенными параметрами? А еще - я не вижу, где у вас прописана функция set_content_disposition(), которая должна проставить в http - заголовках правильный mime - type

Comment: Да. Так и есть. Я просто пока что запустил сервер не более и пытаюсь разобраться в механизме того - как получить доступ к отображению картинок в браузере.
Что для этого требуется - по самому минимуму?

Comment: я рассуждаю так: если бы я сам писал http - сервер для раздачи статики, то тпичными ошибками новичка было бы неправильное формирование заголовком (т.е тех самых mime type) или доступ к файлу в неправильном режииме (его надо считывать с диска как бинарный). Втоая ошибка - маловероятна, а вот первая - может быть.

Comment: что бы лучше понять о чем вы говорите - необходим какой то работающий пример - который можно пощупать.

Comment: пример должен быть на раст?

Comment: да. + желательно связан с работой actix-web.
https://actix.rs/actix-web/actix_web/http/header/struct.ContentDisposition.html
вот эта функиця - но мне сходу тяжело понять как ее встроить в мой существующий код + не до конца понятно что это мне даст в конечном итоге в плане отображения картинок.

Comment: Смотрите, Вы запускаете готовый пример, в котором инкапсулирована вся логика http сервера. То есть "чувак, тебе ничего не надо делать, просто напиши эту команду запуска с 20 параметрами... ты же знаешь, что детально означает каждый из них?"
Из за того, что не все параметры понятны - что то может пойти не так.
можно взять пример простого однопоточного сервера, в котором всё "делается руками" - возможно, такой пример будет понятнее

Comment: я практическ уверен, что дело в функции set_content_disposition, об этом пишут на первой странице примера, о котором Вы пишете в вопросе

Comment: Есть идея. Для проверки - попробуйте рядом с картинкой положить текстовый файл, и посмотреть, будет ли при его открытии другая ошибка?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/VrwyX78c4oEVO2
http://joxi.ru/n2YLbPaHekPG7m
я не уверен конечно что я даже правильно(в плане адреса) обращаюсь к файлу

Comment: Попробуйте запросить файл postman'ом. В среде разработки -всё выглядит работающим, вон, даже favicon браузер у Вашего сервера попросил

Comment: 1) как это сделать?
2) мне же не нужно что бы я картинки получал в результате пост запроса.
Мне необходимо что бы они поттягивались на фронтенд если в этом будет необходимость(если я на фронте в картинке укажу адрес моего удаленного сервера )

Comment: Postman - Это не про post - запрос. Это такая модная универсальная утилита, которая позволяет подёргать сервер за разные места, и при этом показывает больше информации, чем браузер. И еще: не в виндовс дефендер ли дело? виндовс ингда может быть такой настойчивой в попытках никого не пустить к себе...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `Files::new("/static", ".")` укажи вместо точки абсолютный путь до твоей директории static включительно. Например, можно сделать это следующим образом:

```
Files::new(
    "/static",
    std::path::Path::new(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR")).join("static"),
)
```

Comment: http://joxi.ru/BA0QjX0Ip13Zlr
Такой вопрос: если я пытаюсь открыть вот такой файл вместо картинки - получаю вот такой результат: http://joxi.ru/nAypkNxHw90bj2
Если причина в кодировке - то где ее указать(прописать) необходимо?